# Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File fails to be restored after configuring <RuntimeIdentifiers> in dotnet core 2.0 console app

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package, serilog

I added `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` to my dotnet core 2.0 console app. It all went fine. When I add a runtime identifier to my .csproj in order to publish my project into an .exe (win7-x64), I get a Package restore failed error. Please help!

Comment: you're not giving people much to go on - what error for example

Comment: Hi @RubenBartelink. Thanks, The only information that I get is: Error  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ProjectName'. It is just that the nuget package adding process is aborted and Visual Studio gives this generic message.

Comment: There's normally a more detailed error dump somewhere - either trigger the build in verbose mode and look at that, or if in VS, look at the relevant output windows etc. - there's no magic - nobody can figure it out based on what you've supplied/looked at so far - rest assured you're not missing any magic tricks!